# В ASP .NET веб-сервис вместо русских букв приходят знаки вопроса

Tags: c#, asp.net, кодировка, веб-служба

Имеется SOAP веб-сервис, в который приходит строка. Проблема с русскими символами, вместо них приходят знаки вопроса. В самом xml запросе указана кодировка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

В Globalization тоже прописано UTF-8 и регион ru:

```
<globalization fileEncoding='utf-8' 
               requestEncoding='utf-8' 
               responseEncoding='utf-8' 
               culture='ru-RU' 
               uiCulture='ru-RU' />
```

Нашел как исправить на англоязычном stackoverflow, но как-то коряво выглядит. Суть в том, чтобы в global.asax в Application_BeginRequest добавить такой код:

```
if(Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.Equals("text/xml"))
{
  Request.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8";
}
```

Может ли кто-то объяснить в чем причина и как это можно нормально исправить? Подозреваю, что что-то упустил в настройках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел причину, точнее даже три:

1) В первом случае, клиент, когда отправлял запрос, указывал в  request.ContentType = "text/xml", а надо было "text/xml; charset=UTF-8".

2) Во втором случае, ContentType был указан правильно, но запрос отправлялся путем чтения данных из xml файла, но вот сам файл был в другой кодировке.

3) У клиента было в request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=UTF-8" все правильно, но данные он передавал без преобразования в UTF8:

```
byte[] contentBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(body);
```

а надо было так:

```
byte[] contentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
```